# Combining OAuth2 with http basic authentication spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I've implemented OAuth2 using spring boot and spring security. Now I've different set of APIs available and I want to use different authentication methods for it. For e.g I want to use OAuth2 for `/users/**` apis and Http Basic Authentication for `/admin/**` APIs.

However, OAuth2 shouldn't work for `/admin/**` and HTTP basic shouldn't work for `/users/**` APIs.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Security you can have multiple filter chains that handle different requests.
So you can have one that handles requests to the /users/** uri which will have the Basic Authentication filter , and one that handles requests to /admin/** uri which will have the Oauth2 filters. To set this up, you need 2 instances of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

One for Oauth2

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class Oauth2ConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.mvcMatcher("/user/**")
       ......
```

And another for Basic:

```
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class BasicConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.mvcMatcher("/admin/**")
       ......
```

This article explains it in more detail: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points

Also this code does something similar with Digest auth for /admin and Basic for all other. https://github.com/wlesniak/spring-security-authn-authz-course/tree/master/module_2/mod2_crypto_portfolio_digest